# Possible Unity3d UGUI bug

Tags: unity-game-engine

[Example project found here](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/is-this-a-bug.307226/), please load 'TestScene' and play to see the issue. I create a prefab that consists of a canvas containing a button. In an attached script, I move the button off-center in Start(). When I instantiate this prefab, the button would be at the center/origin (0,0,0), not off-center. Somehow the call to move the button in Start() was overridden by something else.

In other words, when a prefab containing a canvas in instantiated within code, its size fields will all be 0 in Start(), But if the prefab is dropped in the scene manually, its size parameters will be set correctly when inspected in Start()...

I cannot make sense of this behavior. Is it a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Really interesting scenario, I think it is a bug. In particular, I noticed that this works around the problem:

```
public class Placement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public RectTransform btn;

    IEnumerator Start()
    {
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        btn.position = new Vector3(100, 100, 0);
    }
}
```

But just setting the script execution order so Placement.cs runs after everything else **did not help**. And in case you're looking for which class to blame, it's the button's `RectTransform`. You can see this by setting the anchor position to something else, like Left. I also tested this script to help with object duplication--is the new object the same as the old one?

```
public class CloneOne : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Awake()
    {
        GameObject go = gameObject;
        DestroyImmediate(this);
        Instantiate (go);
    }
}
```

and found that if I add the clone component to Canvas at runtime, the clone is in the right position, but if I add it to the prefab, it is not.

So it looks like:

1. The `RectTransform`'s initialization code is setting child positions, and it's happening after the other component `Start` methods are called, regardless of execution order. And,
2. This must be some kind of high level initialization, setting state that's not visible in the inspector. I say this because it doesn't happen when the object is created in Editor mode (not playing). (Yes, that means it's a bug. It's silly bug-causing behavior.)

Comment: maybe I misunderstood you, but changing the anchor didnt reveal anything new to me. For me the blame seems to lay on the Canvas, its rectTransform's fields are all set to 0 in Start(), and the whole prefab isn't even listed in the hierarchy when I break in Start(), which I think it should be since start() is called just before Update(). In addition, having "yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();" actually made things worse, since now the button wouldn't move even if I manually drop the prefab into the scene during runtime. So far the only hack is to do all the placement in the first update call

Comment: Strange, you're experiencing something very different than me. The anchor is the square button on the left of the inspector for the rect transform component. And I'm talking about the button, of course. Changing it to "left" made the button go to the left instead of the center. (Continuing to ignore your positioning code.) Here's another interesting bit: setting the button's position in `Start` had no effect--set it the print the value, and it doesn't change. Setting it in a later part of execution has immediate effect.

Comment: And putting the code in `Update` seems a little dirty. It should definitely work to use `yield return null` in `Start` to execute on the next frame.

Comment: I encourage you to report a bug about this. If you're not comfortable doing it, let me know and I'll do it.

Comment: actually setting wait for next frame or null works now. But changing to left does change the position, but not to the correct position. Ill report it as a bug soon.

Comment: I don't have the code in front of me anymore, so I can't comment. I hope you mention in your report that setting Position to execute last (in script execution order) has no effect. There are two nails in the coffin that prove this is a bug: One is the differing behavior depending on whether an object starts in the scene, and the other is the fact that this issue is apparently independent of execution order.

Comment: ah i didnt mention either of these points, because I submitted it before your last comment, and since I dont see how the 1st point relates to this. You can submit it independently though, wouldn't do any harm.

Comment: Good idea. I'll reference your bug if you have a number I can mention to them.